# How to make a page unscrollable?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a page I'm working on that encompasses a vertical drop-down menu. However, when the menu drops down, it pushes the text below it downwards and off the page. This is expected, but this enables the scroll bar on the side of the page. I was wondering it there was a way to get rid of this. In other words, it shouldn't just not scroll, but never even offer the option to scroll.

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want no scrollbar to appear and no scrolling whatsoever to occur, in the CSS for the `div` in which you contain said dropdown use

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will cut off any 'additional content' though; see an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow)

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks for the quick and thorough answer.

Comment: So, when this _doesn't_ work what would be a possible reason why?

Answer (score 7):

Use `overflow: hidden;` on the element you want to hide the scrollbar on.